# Setting form action based on condition

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

How can I change the action of a form? When I show the view I set a var called `ViewData["mode"]` which can be `edit` or `insert`, and in the controller I have two method `Edit()` and `Insert()`, that performs the actions.

```
public class ManagePersonController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult ShowEditForm(string name, string surname, DateTime date)
    {
        ViewData["mode"] = "edit";
        //Do some stuff
        return View("Form");
    }

    public ActionResult ShowInsertForm()
    {
        ViewData["mode"] = "insert";
        //Do some stuff
        return View("Form");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(string name, string surname, DateTime date)
    {
        //do the edit
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Insert(string name, string surname, DateTime date)
    {
        //do the insert
    }

}
```

I wanted to use the same form for both methods but I don't know hot to change the action based on a condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use @Html.ActionLink with dynamic action name

```
@Html.ActionLink((string)ViewData["mode"], (string)ViewData["mode"], "ManagePerson");
```